# How to open 2 URL from C#?

Tags: c#

OK, it sounds easy, I know I can use Process.Start("http://mysite");

But I need to open 2 web sites at one go!! something like

Process.Start("http://mysite");
Process.Start("http://othersite");

I can't get this to work, since the process it opens only the second site.

Any help will be appreciated ,

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

You could try opening each in a new thread.

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Process.Start("http://mysite")));
thread1.Start();

Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Process.Start("http://othersite")));
thread2.Start();

thread1.Join();
thread2.Join();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** Oops, didn't read the whole question, ignore this please :)

Sorry BFree, but i hate it that you force the user to use Internet explorer.

Use this code instead:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.geekpedia.com");
```

Comment: Read his question again. He tried Process.Start("http...") but that doesn't work. I tested it myself to confirm. If you just use Process.Start("http..."); Process.Start("http:..."); it will only open the latter. The way I showed, although only with IE opens both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting a `Thread.Sleep(15000)` between the process start calls. You should then see more clearly what is happening. My guess is it's something in your default browser settings and the second URL is being loaded into the same window the first one was.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Process.Start("iexplore","http://www.google.com");
    Process.Start("iexplore", "http://www.yahoo.com");
```

This will open two copies of IE. Do you want that behavior, or do you want them in one browser tabbed?

Answer (score 0):

It should work exactly as if you run it from windows run (Win-R). The reason is probably in your browser's settings. Check something like "Use same window for opening links" in your default browser's options.